# How to add the number of nodes one by one and then display using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python. Can you tell me how to add nodes one by one to a multigraph and then display the final graph using matplotlib in python and network x. I have added nodes and the code is

```
G = nx.Graph()   
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node('Hello')
K3 = nx.Graph([(0,1),(1,2),(2,0)])
G.add_node(K3)
G.number_of_nodes()
3
```

But finding problem in displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying a `networkx` graph is as easy as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

Your graph, however, will be displayed as 3 separate nodes, as it has no edges added to it. You can add edges to a graph using `add_edge`, `add_edges_from`, or passing a list of edges to `__init__` as explained in the [documentation](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html#edges).